# Llamada ajax a java balanceada entre servidores

Tags: java, ajax, json, jsp, servidor

Parto de que mi aplicación está desplegada entre dos servidores, balanceados, llamemosle servidor1 y servidor2.

Tengo una llamada ajax en .jps a un método action de java. El problema que tengo es que, al acceder a mi web, accedo con unas credenciales de acceso para el servidor1, pero al hacer la llamada Ajax, me hace la petición al servidor2, que ya no tiene esas credenciales de acceso, por lo tanto, falla la llamada... ¿Dónde puede estar el problema y su solución.

Aquí mi código:

```
             $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"${applicationUrl}/cargarDatosAccesoComboLista.action",
            data: 'mCuerpoId='+ valorCuerpo + '&nif=' + "<s:property value='datosSolicitud.numIdentificacionSol'/>",
            success:function(result){

                $('#' + idAcceso).find('option').remove();
                $('#' + idAcceso).append($("<option />").val("").text('No seleccionado'));

                var oposiciones = $.parseJSON(result);

                $.each(oposiciones,function(index, value){
                    var values = value.split(':')
                    $('#' + idAcceso).append($("<option />").val(values[0]).text(values[1]));
                });

                document.getElementById(idAcceso).removeAttribute("disabled");
            },
            error: function(result){

                console.log('Error al cargar las ofertas de empleo');
            }
        });
```

Comment: El problema es en no tener credenciales para S2. ¿Cual es la razón? ¿No te parece que hay un fallo en el diseño de la autenticación de las llamadas? A lo mejor debes replantear este punto.

Comment: ambos servers contienen la misma aplicación? si es así, entre ellos deberían compartir la información de sesiones, si no, es imposible de mantener una sesión abierta entre ambos. Un enfoque comun es guardarlas en alguna base de datos común y leer desde ahí la información de sesión. Yal como dice Evgeni veo un problema de diseño bastante grave.

Comment: Efectivamente si quieres utilizar un balanceador de carga tienes que modificar el diseño de tu backend. Si fuera yo pensara en utilizar autenticación basada en JWT o similar.